# How to get count(*) value 0 in select from where group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get count value 0 if there are no rows that matches the condition.

I have a big table. But, I am posting a truncated table as it explains what I want.

Example

Table1:

```
**name   year   title**
name1    2008   title1
name2    2009   title2
name3    2010   title1
name1    2008   title2
name4    2009   title1
name2    2008   title2
```

I want to show the count of rows for every name where year=2008. So, that if there is no row with year 2008 then. A name and its count 0 should be shown.

Output should be:

```
**name   count**
  name1   2
  name2   1
  name3   0
  name4   0
```

Workaround:

```
select p.name,(select count(*) 
               from table1 b 
               where b.name=p.name) as count 
from table1 p 
where p.year=2008;
```

Tried some more. But, none of them worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
select p.name,
       count(case when p.year=2008 then 1 end) as count 
from table1 p 
group by p.name
```

The query uses *conditional aggregation* so as to conditionally count `year=2008` occurrences of `p.name` values.

Comment: Thanks. :) You saved my half day! Wasted my first half day on this. However, learned some other new things in sql.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it using **DECODE**. Of course, **CASE** is pretty clear and verbose.

```
SELECT NAME,
       COUNT(DECODE(YEAR, 2008, 1)) COUNT
FROM your_table
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY COUNT DESC;
```

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 'name1' NAME, 2008 YEAR FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'name2' NAME, 2009 YEAR FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'name3' NAME, 2010 YEAR FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'name1' NAME, 2008 YEAR FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'name4' NAME, 2009 YEAR FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 'name2' NAME, 2008 YEAR FROM dual
  8  )
  9  --end of sample_Data mimicking real table
 10  SELECT NAME,
 11         COUNT(DECODE(YEAR, 2008, 1)) COUNT
 12  FROM sample_data
 13  GROUP BY NAME
 14  ORDER BY COUNT DESC;

NAME       COUNT
----- ----------
name1          2
name2          1
name4          0
name3          0

SQL>
```

Comment: @sailesh So? Are you confused with the sample_data in the WITH clause used to build a working test case?

Comment: Oops. I am new to this. Sorry!

Comment: @sailesh No problem. We use the WITH clause to build a sample test case just like a static table which is what sample_data is mimicking.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @sailesh You're welcome. You could mark one of the answers which helped you as answered.

Comment: Sure. Waiting for the time limit.

Answer (score 0):

For the data set given, @GiorgosBetsos gives a good answer.

Another, more generalised, answer uses two tables.  One with the data *(a fact table)* and one with the list of names *(a dimension table)*.  That gives the following construct...

```
SELECT
    person_dimension.name,
    COUNT(fact_table.title)
FROM
    person_dimension
LEFT JOIN
    fact_table
        ON  fact_table.person_id = person_dimension.id
        AND fact_table.year = 2008
GROUP BY
    person_dimension.name
```

This way you are also forcing yourself to normalise your data structure.  Although it may be enticing to keep all your data in as few tables as possible e(possibly event just one), that way leads to a lot of pain in Relational Databases.  It is much more standard to separate out facts and dimensions.

One added benefit here is that you can then filter to a sub-set of names very easily.  For example....

```
SELECT
    person_dimension.name,
    COUNT(fact_table.title)
FROM
    person_dimension
LEFT JOIN
    fact_table
        ON  fact_table.person_id = person_dimension.id
        AND fact_table.year = 2008
WHERE
    person_dimension.country = 'Unknown'
GROUP BY
    person_dimension.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  select p.name,
  count(*) over(partition by name) as cnt
  from table1 p where year=2008 
  order by cnt;
```

Comment: count(p.year)? The OP wanted to count ROWS for year=2008.

Comment: still anything @mathguy

Comment: This will not return the "names" that don't have any row with year=2008 in the table, as the OP requested. Do you test your solutions before posting? It is a good practice. Cheers!